# How to link two contacts in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

I very often use the `Details` part of an Outlook contact. I want to store the name of my contacts's boss or personal assistant.

The only option I have is to enter the name of the boss or the PA manually, instead of being able to select it from all my other contacts where they are usually stored.

Can this be done?

Comment: I suspect (though I'm guessing) that this is only possible if you're part of an Active Directory environment.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know for this is to use the contact linking field.

This field is obsolete since Outlook 2013. So it should be enabled in your version. If not you have to modifie the Registry, adding a DWORD-Key `ShowContactFieldObsolete = 1`
[Here is the detailed description for various office versions](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/2013/show-contact-linking-fields-in-outlook-2013/)

Now theres a field visible in each contact window in the bottom right corner. There you can add desired contacts to connect. Connected contacts are shown in each of the connected contacts. They are connected to the existing contacts in your adressbook. So if you change them, the link will also change.

Through this they are not linked like Outlook 2013s "Link Contacts" feature, they are only connected somehow.

You could also put a link in the notes-area of the contact but thats a copy of the actual state of the desired contact. Changes dont update the link in the notes-area.

I dont know if there are sideeffects which I didnt state properly. If so, just comment.